# Proving that $\frac{2n}{n-2}$ is not an integer for all $n > 6$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on problem 1-6 in *Exercises for the Feynman Lectures* and the question asks: Can you explain why there are no crystals that have the shape of a regular pentagon? (Triangles, squares, and hexagons are common in crystal forms).

This is what I have so far:

The interior angle of a polygon with equal $n$-equal sides can be given by:

$$\theta_n = 180° - \frac{(360)}{n}$$

The crystal structure must have equally spaced angles so $\theta_n $ must be an integral number of 360°. Therefore the integral factor $m$ is the number of times $\theta_n$ must be multiplied to span the the entire 360°.

$$360/m = 180 -  \frac{360}{n}$$

$$ m = \frac{2n}{n-2}$$

From this it is easy to see that $n = 5$ would not give an integer however the only values of $n$ for $n \ge 3$ that seem to give an integer are 3, 4 and 6. I want to try to prove that this holds for any $n > 6$ so that there are no integer values of $m$ for $n >  6$.

Comment: Perhaps show the numerator and denominator are relatively prime.

Comment: Hint: $2n = 2(n-2)+4$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{2n}{n-2}=2+\frac4{n-2}$$